# Combine billing page and registration page on one WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to make my registration page and billing page into one so that when a user registers they fill in their address at the same time as well. I've split my login and registration pages , my registration uses the following code to work, it copies over everything that is currently set in my registration page that included some custom stuff including a phone number login and registration function:

```
   
add_shortcode( 'wc_reg_form_bbloomer', 'bbloomer_separate_registration_form' );
    
function bbloomer_separate_registration_form() {
   if ( is_admin() ) return;
   if ( is_user_logged_in() ) return;
   ob_start();
 
   // NOTE: THE FOLLOWING <FORM></FORM> IS COPIED FROM woocommerce\templates\myaccount\form-login.php
   // IF WOOCOMMERCE RELEASES AN UPDATE TO THAT TEMPLATE, YOU MUST CHANGE THIS ACCORDINGLY
 
   do_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form' );
 
   ?>
      <form method="post" class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-register register" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_tag' ); ?> >
 
         <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start' ); ?>
 
         <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_username' ) ) : ?>
 
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
               <label for="reg_username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
               <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="reg_username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
            </p>
 
         <?php endif; ?>
 
         <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="reg_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['email'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
         </p>
 
         <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ) : ?>
 
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
               <label for="reg_password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
               <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" autocomplete="new-password" />
            </p>
 
         <?php else : ?>
 
            <p><?php esc_html_e( 'A password will be sent to your email address.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
 
         <?php endif; ?>
 
         <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form' ); ?>
 
         <p class="woocommerce-FormRow form-row">
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-register', 'woocommerce-register-nonce' ); ?>
            <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-register__submit" name="register" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Next', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Next', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
         </p>
 
         <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_end' ); ?>
 
      </form>
 
   <?php
     
   return ob_get_clean();
}
```

To be created.

My billing form also has alot of custom code in the means of:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_billing_fields');


function custom_woocommerce_billing_fields($fields)
{


    
    
    
    
          $fields['billing_title'] = array(
         'label' => __('Title', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => _x('Title', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'required' => false, // if field is required or not
        'clear' => false, // add clear or not
        'type'  => 'select',
        'options'   => array(
         '' => 'Please select',
                        'Mr.'   => 'Mr', 
                        'Ms.'   => 'Ms',
                        'Mrs'   => 'Mrs',
                        
        ),    
        'class' => array('my-css'),
        'priority' => 9,// 
   );
     
              $fields['billing_condition'] = array(
         'label' => __('Type Of Residency', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => _x('', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'required' => true, // if field is required or not
        'clear' => false, // add clear or not
        'type'  => 'select',
        'options'   => array(
         '' => 'Please select your residency type',
                        'house' => 'House', 
                        'complex'   => 'Complex/Flats',
                       
                        
        ),    
        'class' => array('my-css'),
        'priority' => 49,// 
   );

    


    $fields['billing_complex_address'] = array(
        'label' => __('Complex Address', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => _x('E.g Batulta Manor Yellow Tail Road', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'required' => false, // if field is required or not
        'clear' => false, // add clear or not
        'type' => 'text', // add field type
        'class' => array('my-css') ,// add class name
         'priority' => 52,
    );
    
        
      
      $fields['billing_complex_name'] = array(
         'label' => __('Complex Name', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => _x('E.g Raslouw Gardens', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'required' => false, // if field is required or not
        'clear' => false, // add clear or not
        'type' => 'select',// add field type
          'options'     => array(
         '' => 'Please select',
               'himalayaheights'=> 'Himalaya Heights',
              'irelandhills'=>'Ireland Hills',
              'other' => 'Other',
                         
    
        ),
        'class' => array('my-css'),
          'priority' => 51,// 
   );

          $fields['billing_complex_address_inside'] = array(
         'label' => __('Address Inside The Complex', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => _x('E.g ERF 345 or 1 Bathtta Villas', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'required' => false, // if field is required or not
        'clear' => false, // add clear or not
        'type' => 'text', // add field type
        'class' => array('my-css'),
              'priority' => 53,// 
   );
    
    
              $fields['billing_suburb'] = array(
         'label' => __('Your Suburb', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => _x('Your Suburb', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'required' => false, // if field is required or not
        'clear' => false, // add clear or not
        'type'  => 'select',
        'options'   => array(
         '' => 'Please select',
                        
                        'VAL'   => 'Valhalla',
                        'OTH'   => 'Other'
        ),    
        'class' => array('my-css'),
        'priority' => 54, 
   );
    
    

    return $fields;

}
```

How do I go about combining these two into one ? Is there a way to just bring in the contents somehow and populate the registration page with the custom billing page setup or some other way cause I'm stumped and also stumped at the part of saving the address whilst creating the user at the same time as well.